# .NET hashtable: How to simulate "Load factor too high" exception

Tags: .net, hashtable

Our production repeatedly met "Hashtable insert failed. Load factor too high". 
1. How could I simulate this kind of exception?
2. If this sort of exception is thrown, would the existing key/value will disappear?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you want to simulate the exception, or the conditions that cause the exception in production?

Comment: i'd like to simulate the exception

Answer (score 2):

This contains a relevant explanation:  http://blogs.msdn.com/toddca/archive/2007/01/26/hashtable-insert-failed-load-factor-too-high.aspx

Comment: Why the blog mentioned KB 927579? Isn't it 968432?

Comment: I don't know I didn't write the blog

Answer (score 1):

In .NET 2.0, this error is almost always caused by multiple threads modifying the Hashtable at the same time.

There is a [HotFix for .NET 3.5](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB968432)

See [Hashtable insert failed. Load factor too high](http://blogs.msdn.com/toddca/archive/2007/01/26/hashtable-insert-failed-load-factor-too-high.aspx) 
and [FIX: "InvalidOperationException, Load Factor Too High" When You Use a Hashtable Collection](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;831730)

Comment: Why the blog mentioned KB 927579? Isn't it 968432?

Comment: Our sys admins indicated 968432 is installed, but the error seemed still existing.

Comment: BTW: we are using .NET 2.0 on Win2003